# Whats the command to find Nic cards serial numbers in linux?

Tags: linux, nic

Whats the command to find Nic cards serial  numbers in linux  ? I tried dmidecode options and lshow

may be I missed some thing

Comment: You might try asking this question on the SuperUser or AskUbuntu sites.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about serial numbers, but [lspci](http://mj.ucw.cz/pciutils.html) gives me the following information about my ethernet card:

```
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 02)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't mucked with your MAC address since bootup, it will be globally unique.  See http://www.coffer.com/mac_info/locate-unix.html

NICs aren't required to have any other serial number than that, and if they do it might not be electronically readable.

Answer (score 1):

Use "ifconfig" to get each ports **globally unique** *MAC Addresses*

```
ifconfig -a
```

For *all* adapters

Answer (score 1):

Use `lspci -v` or `lspci -v | grep Serial`. The verbose option gives you more detail where you may find the serial number. If you have the vendor ID, it will be much easier to sift through the list to find the card that you are looking for by using for example one of these commands and grepping for 'Serial'.

- For intel network cards, use `lspci -d 8086: -v`
- For netronome network cards, use `lspci -d 19ee: -v`
- For mellanox network cards, use `lspci -d 15b3: -v`